# How does math.min actually work?

Tags: java, math, min, built-in

I understand that all of the math functions in java are built in. But I was wondering out of curiosity how `Math.min()` actually works?

I checked the java documentation and couldn't find anything to help me. I'm quite new to java.

Comment: Use the source (Math.java):

`public static int min(int a, int b) {
        return (a <= b) ? a : b;
    }`

Comment: If you don't have an IDE at hand, [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/) can help a lot.

Comment: Read the source, its just one line in many cases.

Comment: How it works is undefined. There are several possible ways it could be written, but they all have to result in the same thing, as specified in the Javadoc. Unclear what you're really asking.

Comment: The point is that you *don't need to know* how a library works, just use it per the documentation.   Of course, intellectual curiosity is a good thing.  You just need to hold the two things apart in your mind, especially when writing code ("if it's not in the doc I don't know it").

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### int

```
public static int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

#### long

```
public static long min(long a, long b) {
     return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

#### float

```
public static float min(float a, float b) {
    if (a != a) return a;   // a is NaN
    if ((a == 0.0f) && (b == 0.0f) && (Float.floatToIntBits(b) == negativeZeroFloatBits)) {
         return b;
    }
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
 }
```

#### double

```
public static double min(double a, double b) {
    if (a != a) return a;   // a is NaN
    if ((a == 0.0d) && (b == 0.0d) && (Double.doubleToLongBits(b) == negativeZeroDoubleBits)) {
        return b;
    }
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

More info: [Here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java)

Answer (score 10):

**[Java 7 documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#min%28int,%20int%29)**:

> Returns the smaller of two int values. That is, the result the argument closer to the value of Integer.MIN_VALUE. If the arguments have the same value, the result is that same value.

**Behaviour**:

```
Math.min(1, 2) => 1
Math.min(1F, 2) => 1F
Math.min(3D, 2F) => 2D
Math.min(-0F, 0F) => -0F
Math.min(0D, -0D) => -0D
Math.min(Float.NaN, -2) => Float.NaN
Math.min(-2F, Double.NaN) => Double.NaN
```

**java.lang.Math and java.lang.StrictMath Source**:

```
public static int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

**java.lang.Math Bytecode (`javap -c Math.class` of Oracle's JDK's JRE's rt.jar)**:

```
public static int min(int, int);
Code:
   0: iload_0           // loads a onto the stack
   1: iload_1           // loads b onto the stack
   2: if_icmpgt     9   // pops two ints (a, b) from the stack
                        // and compares them
                        // if b>a, the jvm continues at label 9
                        // else, at the next instruction, 5
                        // icmpgt is for integer-compare-greater-than
   5: iload_0           // loads a onto the stack
   6: goto          10  // jumps to label 10
   9: iload_1           // loads 
  10: ireturn           // returns the currently loaded integer
```

If the comparison at **5** is true, **a** will be loaded, the jvm will jump to **10** and return **a**,
if the comparison yields false, it will jump to **9**, which will load and return **b**.

**Intrinsics**:

[This .hpp file](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/hotspot/file/87ee5ee27509/src/share/vm/classfile/vmSymbols.hpp#l652) of the Java 8 Hotspot JVM hints that it optimizes Math.min even further with optimized machine code:

```
do_intrinsic(_min, java_lang_Math, min_name, int2_int_signature, F_S)
```

This means the above bytecode won't be executed by the Java 8 Hotspot JVM. However, this differs from JVM to JVM, which is why I also explained the bytecode!

Hopefully, now you know all there is to know about Math.min! :)

Answer (score 3):

Just check the [Math.java source file](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/lang/Math.java#Math.min%28int,int%29) :

```
public static int min(int a, int b) {
    return (a <= b) ? a : b;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

[Reference](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/math_min_int.htm)

> The **java.lang.Math.min(int a, int b)** returns the smaller of two int values. That is, the result is the value closer to negative infinity. If the arguments have the same value, the result is that same value. If either value is NaN, then the result is NaN. Unlike the numerical comparison operators, this method considers negative zero to be strictly smaller than positive zero. If one argument is positive zero and the other is negative zero, the result is negative zero.

For example

```
System.out.println(Math.min(1111, 1000));
```

Output as

```
1000
```

It displays minimum value from the `Math.min()`

Comment: Thank you very much for locating that piece of documentation. It really helps me understand it more.

Answer (score 2):

Some efficient form of

```
math.min(a,b) = public static int min (a, b) {
  if(a<=b) return a;
  else return b;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, the X.L. Ant had the exact form of it, but yours still helped me understand it a bit more fully.

Answer (score -1):

In Java, the `Math.min(a, b)` function is used to determine the minimum value between two numbers `a` and `b`. It returns the smaller of the two values.

The `Math.min()` method is a static method provided by the `Math` class in Java's standard library. It accepts two parameters of numeric data types (such as `int`, `double`, `float`, etc.) and returns the smaller value among them.
Here's how the `Math.min()` method works:

1. If `a` is less than `b`, the method returns `a`.
2. If `b` is less than or equal to `a`, the method returns `b`.
3. If `a` and `b` are equal, the method returns either `a` or `b`.
   Here's an example usage of `Math.min()` in Java:

   int a = 5;
   int b = 3;
   int minimum = Math.min(a, b);
   System.out.println("The minimum value is: " + minimum);

In this example, the output will be `The minimum value is: 3`, as `b` is the smaller value between `a` and `b`.

Comment: To me, your answer is an explanation of what method [min](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Math.html#min(int,int)) does and not how it does it - which is what was asked for.